# LDAP query that retrieves all the groups to which the user has access

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I need a LDAP query that retrieves all the groups to which the user has access.
I´m using Java and must properly configure attributes (searchbase, searchFilter and searchCtls) as follows

```
String searchBase = "OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=net";
String searchFilter = "(objectClass=*)";
String returnedAtts[] = { "tokenGroups" };
SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE);
searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
```

Answer (score 1):

We have defined many [LDAP queries](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches) for Microsoft Active Directory (Assuming AD by OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=net).

-jim